# how to create a new command to "use chrome to open a URL to search a word to learn English online conveniently" in windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, vbscript

my friends. Those are my requirenments:

The url has two parts:

- first part is fixed:

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/hello_1?q=

- another part is any word I want to search. For example "hello"

now I can only open dictionary web page by input this command

```
chrome https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/hello_1?q=
```

but I need to input full URL to do that search in one step.

```
chrome https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/hello_1?q=hello
```

But the problems are:

- the comand are too long, if I can use a alias it would be great. For example `dict hello`.
- each time the word I need to search is different.
  Could you help me to implementment this command line dictionary tool?
  Any help would be much appreate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following VBScript code:

```
Dim sURL
Dim sSearch 
Dim objShell

sSearch = "hello"
sURL = "https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/" & sSearch & "_1?q=" & sSearch

set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShell.ShellExecute "chrome.exe", sURL, "", "", 1
```

If you want to automate this you can make a Sub out of it and call it as you iterate through your dictionary:

```
Dim iContinue
Dim sSearchString

sSearchString = "hello"
iContinue = vbYes

Do While iContinue = vbYes
    sSearchString = InputBox("Enter search string:", "Dictionary Lookup", sSearchString) 
    Search sSearchString
    iContinue = MsgBox("Would you like to make another search?", vbYesNo)
Loop

Sub Search(p_sSearchString)
    Dim sURL
    Dim objShell

    sURL = "https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/" & p_sSearchString & "_1?q=" & p_sSearchString

    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    objShell.ShellExecute "chrome.exe", sURL, "", "", 1

End Sub
```

Comment: The first one which does not have a pop up window can only search fixed "hello" cause I don't know how to input new word.

Comment: BTW. And does it also possible that that pop up window can stay active for next search other than close after first use?

Comment: Yes, you can have it display the `InputBox` again, until the user clears out the text or searches for the same text again. You can approach this many ways... read up on `Do While` loops in VBScript. You can post a new question if you need help with your loop.

Answer (score 2):

In batch you can do something like that :

```
@echo off
Mode 70,4 & color 0A
Title Open dictionary web page by input 
Set "URL=https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/"
:Main
cls
echo(
echo Type the word to search in dictionary
set /P "Dict="
Start "" Chrome "%URL%%Dict%"
TimeOut /T 1 /NoBreak>nul
Goto:Main
```

Comment: It has compile error from my local test. D:\Luxembourg\dict.vbs(1, 1) Microsoft VBScript Compiler error: Invalid character.

Comment: Save it as dict.bat, because it is a batch file not a vbscript file !

Comment: Yep. Saving as .bat file is working alsolutely cool for me. Thank you very much